# AFNetworking cancel post request

Tags: afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation, request-cancelling

i know, this question ask before. But not working for me this scenario. i am working on AFNetworking for transfer layer. My code below.

AFHTTPRequestOperation *post;
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;

---

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSMutableDictionary *paramDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;

    delegate = (id<ConnectionUtilDelegate>) delegateObject;

    for (Parameter *param in parameterArray)
    {
        [paramDict setObject:param.value forKey:param.name];
    }
    NSDictionary *params = paramDict;
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
    post = [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [delegate requestCompleted:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [delegate requestFailed:error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

this is my post request. it's work like charm. But sometimes some request could be late. For instance, i send 2 different post request this name P1(Post 1) and P2(Post 2). if these request response return as a R1(Response 1) and than R2( response 2) is ok for me. But if this request response return as a R2(Response 2) and than R1(Response 1) its a cause for my app. So i want to cancel old request when i send  new request. and

[post cancel];

Error:
[AFHTTPRequestOperation cancel]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1723cbf0

not working for me. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your code, you create a new `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`instance for each request and then perform `cancelAllOperations` over the operationQueue of newly created `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. I suggest you creating a sharedManager of type `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and use this singleton object for all your requests:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

Then, you can cancel all requests before performing a new request using:

```
+ (void)cancelAllRequests {
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

When you call above method, all requests will fail and `failure`block will be called. So you need to check if operation is `cancelled` in failure block. And here comes the final code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManager];
NSMutableDictionary *paramDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;


delegate = (id<ConnectionUtilDelegate>) delegateObject;

for (Parameter *param in parameterArray)
{
    [paramDict setObject:param.value forKey:param.name];
}
NSDictionary *params = paramDict;

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *post = [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] parameters:params

success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [delegate requestCompleted:responseObject];

}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (!operation.cancelled) {
        [delegate requestFailed:error];
    }
}];

[post start];
```